# Login to mysql from command line windows 7, xamppv3.0.12 and Mysql 5.5.25a

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to login to mysql as root with no password from windows command line. But getting syntax error.

```
mysql> -u root -p test;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u ro
ot -p test' at line 1
mysql>
```

What is wrong with my syntax. I am using xampp and Mysql 5.5.25a - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is wrong with my syntax.

Everything is wrong. `-u root -p test` are command line arguments to the actual command `mysqld` or `mysql.exe`. Where is the command?

Second, with posted code I see you already have logged on (by seeing the `mysql>` prompt). In that case what for `-u root -p test`? Rather, you probably want to execute a command/query.

Comment: Yes exactly. I already logged in. I just launch the mysql.exe from xampp/mysql/bin/mysql.exe which automatically logged in as some other user. I think mysqladmin.

Comment: Correct, You are already logged in. Now you can run some query if you want to or exit/quit from there. BTW, consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You are already logged into MySQL, that's what the prompt is telling you:

```
mysql>
```

Now you're expected to type SQL or internal commands. If you want to type shell commands you first need to exit:

```
mysql> exit
Bye

C:\>dir C:
 El volumen de la unidad C es Sistema
 El número de serie del volumen es: A9FF-4083

 Directorio de C:\

03/01/2008  10:25             1.024 .rnd
18/09/2006  23:43                24 autoexec.bat
18/09/2006  23:43                10 config.sys
[...]
```